# Experimenting with data set

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I have the following code that I am trying which works well for training.

As an exercise I am trying to convert it to a dataset and train on the dataset but fails to do so.

```
def gen_labels(series, nums):
  raw_labels=[]
  labels =[]
  for i in range(0,nums):
    sum = 0
    for j in range(0,28):
      for k in range(0,28):        
        sum+=(math.cos(series[i][j][k])+j*2-k*2)*(math.sin(series[i][j][k])+j*2-k*2)
    n = random.random()
    sum = sum+(n-0.5)*28*28*100
    raw_labels.append(sum)   
    if sum > 405000:
      sum = 1.0
    else:
      sum = 0.0
    labels.append(sum)  
  print(raw_labels)  
  return np.asarray(labels)

num_samples = 100
series = np.random.rand(num_samples,28,28)
labels = gen_labels(series,num_samples)

valid_series = np.random.rand(num_samples,28,28)
valid_labels = gen_labels(valid_series,num_samples)


input = tf.keras.layers.Input((28,28,1))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu")(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(input, x)
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(series, labels, epochs=30,verbose=2, validation_data = (valid_series, valid_labels))
```

I tried a few things like trying to merge the series and the labels but I am failing to do so:

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
...
history = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=30,verbose=2, validation_data = vtrain_ds)
```

The last thing I tried was to make my series a (100,28,28,1) shape and store the result on the last dimension.

```
def gen_labels(series, nums):
  raw_labels=[]
  labels =[]
  series = np.expand_dims(series, axis=-1)
  for i in range(0,nums):
    sum = 0
    for j in range(0,28):
      for k in range(0,28):        
        sum+=(math.cos(series[i][j][k])+j*2-k*2)*(math.sin(series[i][j][k])+j*2-k*2)
    n = random.random()
    sum = sum+(n-0.5)*28*28*100
    raw_labels.append(sum)   
    if sum > 405000:
      sum = 1.0
    else:
      sum = 0.0
    labels.append(sum)
    series[i][j][k][0] = sum
  print(series)    
  return series
```

but when training I would get a :
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28, 28, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_6'), name='input_6', description="created by layer 'input_6'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (28, 28, 1, 1)
Initially I wanted to do something similar to timeseries where I would put the last column into a separate dimension using the map method ie

```
dataset = dataset.map(lambda w: (w[:-1], w[1:]))
```

What do you think is the best way to do if I want to use a dataset in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your data is, but you need to specify labels when creating your dataset, like so: `train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((series,labels))`

Also, if it is a binary classification problem, using `loss='binary_crossentropy'` is more appropriate.

You will also need to reshape your data using `data.reshape(28,28,1)`

Finally, you should stop using variables variable names like `sum` and `input`. Those are reserved keywords and storing a variable in those may cause unintended results.

Creating the dataset like so should work. Need to batch the dataset. In this example, `series` is of shape `(n_samples,28,28,1)`

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((series,labels)).batch(5)
valid_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((valid_series,valid_labels)).batch(5)
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your comments for sum and input as well. I am wondering if there is a convention or a list of known keywords I should avoid.

Comment: Regarding data.reshape(28,28,21) is it series.reshape(28,28,1) I tried on the series with 28,28,1 but it looks strange so I tried(100,28,28,1) which is the number of inputs without success, I am currently checking the dataset api to see if there is anything there

Comment: Yes, you should be reshaping to (100,28,28,1). You also need to replace the original variable, like this : series = series.reshape(100,28,28,1). 
As for the naming, you can see reserved keywords are in orange in the code parts. Avoid those words.

Comment: Thanks, I think I don't get the colors because of my editor will check with pycharm in a moment. Regarding the reshaping if I do (100,28,28,1) tensorflow is complaining on the fit method that the shape is (28,28,1,1) but if I don't do the reshape it complains that the shape is (28,28)

Comment: Edited my answer. You need to batch your dataset.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be training well, but I am wondering why batch makes it work.

Comment: I experimented a bit more and it looks like the reshape is not necessary just making it a batch dataset works fine.